# pencil texture in drawing app

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, core-graphics, quartz-core

I am developing an drawing application, I would like to have pencil effect like Paper (Fifty Three) app on App Store. Can anyone guide me a way to do this? I have try UIBezierPath strokeWithBlendMode but not success.

Thanks